# MacBook Pro (M1) reports more disk space used than available on system

Tags: hard-drive, storage, apple-silicon

Hope the title is clear enough. When I go to System settings > General > Storage, the amount of used space showed is larger than the real actual disk capacity. Was wondering why this is so? I don't used iCloud.

For example: it says all my files are in total about 1.4TB, although the physical disk capacity is only about 1TB.

Can't find any explaination online about this weird incorrect reporting of the used capacity vs the real capacity, so I hope someone can shed some light on this :).

Comment: Can we see your evidence for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [macOS 10.13 (High Sierra)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_High_Sierra) [Apple](https://www.apple.com) has been using the [APFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System) file system.
This has some features such as [Space Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Space_sharing) which then lead to odd volume and file size reporting such as what you have noticed.

I think that it is reporting higher storage amount because if you were to copy all your files to a non APFS formatted volume, that is how much space you would need.